# Why can't I take correct id of button jQuery in django loop in template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, post

The problem is this: in my loop in the template, I display the + and - buttons for the number of each product in the cart, while receiving the data and sending it to the server, where I actually process it, and increasing that amount of the product in the cart.

Template

```
<td class="info col-md-3">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="minus" class="btn btn-danger minus" data-id="{{obj.id}}" type="button">-</button>
                            </span>
                            <input id="calc-button" type="text" class="form-control calc-button" data-id="{{obj.id}}" value="{{obj.quantity}}">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button id="plus" class="btn btn-success plus" data-id="{{obj.id}}" type="button">+</button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                </td>
```

and my view

```
class MainCartPlusValue(View):

def post(self, request):
    print(request.POST)
    a = dict()
    a = {
        'id': request.POST['id'],
        'counts': request.POST['counts']
    }
    obj = Dishes.objects.get(id=request.POST['id'])
    product = get_object_or_404(Dishes, id=obj.id)
    """не работает :("""
    # if request.POST['counts'] == 3:
    #     cartremove = MainCartRemove
    #     cartremove.get(self=cartremove.self, request=request, key='remove', pk=obj.id)
    """посюда("""
    cart = Cart(request)
    cart.add(item=product, quantity=request.POST['counts'], update_quantity=True)
    return JsonResponse(a)
```

if need it my cart

```
 def add(self, item, quantity=1, update_quantity=False):
    product_id = item.id
    if product_id not in self.cart:
        self.cart[product_id] = {'quantity': item.counts,
                                 'price': str(item.price),
                                 'name': str(item.name),
                                 'id': item.id
                                 }
    if update_quantity:
        self.cart[product_id]['quantity'] = quantity
        print(self.cart[product_id]['quantity'])
    self.session['cart'] = self.cart
    self.session.modified = True
```

```html
    $(function () {
$('.minus').click(function(){
 $(".calc-button").val(parseInt($(".calc-button").val())-1),
 alert( $(".calc-button").val());
 const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
 $.ajax({
      url: '/cart/plusValue/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'id': $(".minus").data("id"),
        'counts': $(".calc-button").val(),
      },
       success: function(data) {
        alert("Вы кликнули на кнопку и ее значение = "+ data['counts']);
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
$('.plus').click(function(){
 $(".calc-button").val(parseInt($(".calc-button").val())+1),
 alert( $(".calc-button").val());
 const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
 $.ajax({
      url: '/cart/plusValue/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'id': $(".plus").data("id"),
        'counts': $(".calc-button").val(),
      },
       success: function(data) {
        alert("Вы кликнули на кнопку и ее значение = "+ data['counts']);
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
});
```

and in the end result, my code works, I increase the number and it changes.
BUT, at the same time, the number of all objects on the page changes before the page is updated by the same number, for example, if there was 1, then all of them will have 2. and after the update, it will be reset and 2 will remain only in the first position. I looked in the server logs using print (request.POST ['id'] there is everywhere id = of the first position, because I am inclined to believe the wrong code in the view or js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
$(function () {
$('.minus').click(function(){
 $(".calc-button").val(parseInt($(this).val())-1);
 alert( $(".calc-button").val());
 const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
 $.ajax({
      url: '/cart/plusValue/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'id': $(this).data("id"),
        'counts': $(".calc-button").val(),
      },
       success: function(data) {
        alert("Вы кликнули на кнопку и ее значение = "+ data['counts']);
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
$('.plus').click(function(){
 $(".calc-button").val(parseInt($(this).val())+1);
 alert( $(".calc-button").val());
 const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    }
});
 $.ajax({
      url: '/cart/plusValue/',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        'id': $(this).data("id"),
        'counts': $(".calc-button").val(),
      },
       success: function(data) {
        alert("Вы кликнули на кнопку и ее значение = "+ data['counts']);
        console.log(data);
    }
    });
});
});
```

thanks to **Maciej Rogosz** and my **friend**, he gave me the correct idea that ajax works with the same id. I am actually attaching the corrected script. it works, correctly. Yes, graphically, the data changes for everyone at the same time, but when the pages are refreshed, the data looks correct

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're looping correctly through cart items? To me it seems all the buttons have the same `data-id`, hence all are updated with AJAX call.
So in your template, you should probably run a loop:

```
{% for key, value in self.cart.items %}
    ...here hoes listing the products
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: in such a case, if I do this, I get an error. I have a lot of values ​​in my cart, how can I display quantaty specifically, or I get 4 buttons each. It just looks like you are right, but I don’t understand how to fix it

Comment: in the browser, I see from the screenshot that js tells me that you have a lot of the same id. but the preview shows that the id of the buttons are different, this converges with what you say and at the same time confuses me because the numbers are different